# Adding a private function to ADT List causing errors, strange fix

Tags: java, debugging, data-structures

Im taking a class on Java datastructures and we have to add a method,

```
  private boolean contains(T anEntry, Node startNode)
```

to LList2.java that you can find in the code below, however adding this method caused eclipse IDE to display errors and warnings. I was able to fix the errors by adding the function:

Error:

```
  The type LList2<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ListInterface<T>.contains(T)  LList.java
```

addition:

```
      public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
            return false;
    }
```

Also changing    public boolean contains(T anEntry); public to private causes a lot of errors. I do not understand what is going on and why this solved the problem and allowed me to compile. In testing everything seems to work correctly. Can anyone explain whats going on, and how to fix it so I don't need this extra method?

I have put the 3 java source files in PasteBin here:
        LList2.java - http://pastebin.com/HnABCsj4
        ListInterface.java - http://pastebin.com/yhTviUAH
        TestList2.java - http://pastebin.com/9EgTV2mB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListInterface` has `public boolean contains(T anEntry);` method that you must override. You only have `public boolean contains2(T anEntry)` or `public boolean contains(T anEntry, Node startNode)` in your `LList2` class, both doesn't override the interface method.

So you need to implement this method too. This is also the error when you change the method to be private, as in the interface it is declared public.

BTW, It is very recommend you to add `@Override` annotation to all methods that override an interface method. This way you'd see the contains2 error.

Comment: I did its in LList2.java on Line 180 and the method contains2() calls the private contains and uses it recursively on line 176 to walk through the ADT list.

Comment: contains(T anEntry, Node startNode) does **not** override contains2(T anEntry). The method signature must be the same.

Comment: I had accidentally removed the original public boolean contains(T anEntry); method as you said it needed to be overridden. Adding it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

All your non implemented methods in the interface ListInterface must be implemented in subclasses.
Compiler will complain about any missing implementation.